# To visualize collisional region

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way to visualize collision (box, cylinder etc.) defined in SDF? If I'm not mistaken, we still need to give Gazebo visual and collision information separately (as found in [another thread](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4606/how-to-set-the-visual-and-collision-at-ones-using/)). So I'm debugging the collisional region by iterating the following steps many times, which is very cumbersome to me.

1. Edit sdf
2. Run Gazebo
3. Run a robot to try hitting the defined but transparent collision region. If it fails to hit, go back to step 1.

User's operation environment: Gazebo 2.2, ROS Indigo on Ubuntu Trusty

Since I'm using ROS, I can use RViz if there's a feature for this. Also for development purpose, upgrading Gazebo can be an option if only higher version software has a functionality, but the users will run the resulted files on Gazebo 2.2 (or any version that is compatible with ROS Indigo without tweak).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8959/to-visualize-collisional-region/) by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-06-21**:
There should be an option on the top menu bar to `View` -> `Show Collisions`, does that appear for you?

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2015-06-21**:
@chapulina that does it. If you repost it as an answer I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-06-21**:
Glad it worked. I was wondering if it wasn't there for Gazebo 2.2 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There should be an option on the top menu bar to View -> Show Collisions.

To show collisions for a single model, right-click the model and choose `View` -> `Show collision`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0